# Cubic Trees in graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, trees

A tree in graph theory would be called "Cubic" If every non-leaf vertex has degree 3. Are there any cubic trees with "even" number of edges?

I have tried different patterns yet it gives me odd number of edges,
Are an even number of edges possible?

Comment: What about the tree with one node and zero edges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that a tree has one fewer edge than nodes ($m=n{-}1$).

Suppose the cubic tree has $\ell$ leaves out of $n$ nodes. Then by the degree sum of nodes, $\ell + 3(n-\ell)$,  the number of edges $m = (\ell + 3(n-\ell))/2$; then

$n-1=(\ell + 3(n-\ell))/2 \\
2n-2 = 3n-2\ell \\
2\ell - 2 = n $

Thus the number of nodes $n$ is even and the number of edges is odd. As a bonus, the number of interior nodes is two less than the number of leaves, $n{-}\ell = \ell{-}2$.

Comment: Thus, the even number of edges at the end are not feasible?

Comment: The number of edges is always odd for a graph of the type described. I don't know what you mean by "at the end".

Comment: @MandySidhu it occurs to me that, with the addition of one edge and a node at the root, these constructs are basically [full binary trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees)

Answer (score 2):

Take a cubic tree, and pull off a leaf. This leaves a tree, but with
one bad vertex, of degree $2$. Merge together the edges emerging
from this vertex, and you get a cubic tree, with two fewer edges.
Now use induction.

Comment: Even after removing a leave, I Need to satisfy degree 3 condition and because of that the total number of edges stay odd after induction,
Can you please elaborate on how induction would result in total edges to be even.

Answer (score 1):

Start at a leaf, and count one edge. Either you are done, or there are two edges meeting the one you already have. Those two edges mark out a further two vertices. Each vertex you visit if you keep going has either zero or two more edges to count. The tree is connected so you visit each vertex this way. At each stage you add an even number of edges, and you started with one, so the final total will be odd.

Comment: So what you're implying is that the total number of edges at the end cannot be even?

Comment: @MandySidhu Indeed, the number of edges has to be odd. Joffan's answer gives a calculation which shows this.